# Multiple Push notifications in android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-push-notification

I am working on Android application in which I am getting push notifications. I have searched many answers in different forums as well but didn't find a suitable solution for this problem. I have even tried to change `Notification ID` as well for not to get multiple pushes. I have used `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but it's not working as well.

My code:

```
public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, Intent intent) {

            // Check for empty push message
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
                return;

            if (isAppIsInBackground(mContext)) {
                // notification icon
                int icon = R.mipmap.ic_logo;



                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                mContext,
                                0,
                                intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                        );

                NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        mContext);
                Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .build();

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(count++, notification);
            } else {
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("message", message);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NOTIFICATION_ID++ no count++





final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext, CHANNEL_ID);

        Notification notification;

        if (iconBitMap == null) {
            //When Inbox Style is applied, user can expand the notification

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            inboxStyle.addLine(message);

            notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(iconBitMap)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())

                    .setContentText(message)
                    .build();

        } else {
            //If Bitmap is created from URL, show big icon
            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
            bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
            bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(iconBitMap);
            notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(iconBitMap)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setBadgeIconType( 4 )
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())

                    .build();
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notification);

    }
}
```